The smallest area triangle containing a convex hexagon
Recently I came across that article
(Unfortunately, I do not have access to it at the moment.) and played on  its theme.
Here are my trials. Let us consider a convex hexagon
P = Polygon[{{-2, 0}, {-1, 5/2}, {3/2, 3/2}, {2, 0}, {1, -7/2}, {-1, -3/2}}];
reg = Region[P];

and find the smallest area triangle T containing P.
To derive the conditions for $T \supset P$ we make use of synthetic geometry, namely of
a = GeometricSolveValues[ GeometricScene[{q1, q2, q3, p1 -> {-2, 0}, p2 -> {-1, 5/2}, 
p3 -> {3/2, 3/2}, p4 -> {2, 0}, p5 -> {1, -7/2},  p6 -> {-1, -3/2}}, 
{Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}], GeometricAssertion[Polygon[{q1, q2, q3}], "Convex"]&& 
p1 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3}] && p2 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3}] &&  
p3 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3}] &&p4 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3}] && 
p5 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3}] && p6 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2 q3}]}],
 {q1, q2, q3, Area[Polygon[{q1, q2, q3}]]}] // FullSimplify


{{q1 if condition,q2 if condition,q3 if condition,Area[Polygon[{q1,q2,q3}]] if condition}}

All  four conditions are the same. The required condition is complicated and difficult to work with:
a[[1, 1, 2]]


(Indexed[ q1, {2}] (2 + Indexed[q2, {1}]) - (2 +  Indexed[q1, {1}]) Indexed[q2, {2}]) (Indexed[ q2, {2}] (2 + Indexed[q3, {1}]) - (2 + Indexed[q2, {1}]) Indexed[q3, {2}]) > 0 &&... && 1/4 (-Indexed[q1, {2}] -   1/2 (3 + 2 Indexed[q1, {2}]) Indexed[q2, {1}] +  Indexed[q2, {2}] +   Indexed[q1, {1}] (3/2 + Indexed[q2, {2}])) ((Indexed[q1, {2}] -  Indexed[q2, {2}]) Indexed[q3, {1}] +   Indexed[q1, {1}] (Indexed[q2, {2}] - Indexed[q3, {2}]) +  Indexed[q2, {1}] (-Indexed[q1, {2}] + Indexed[q3, {2}])) > 0 &&  Indexed[p1, {1}] == -2 && Indexed[p1, {2}] == 0 &&  Indexed[p2, {1}] == -1 && 2 Indexed[p2, {2}] == 5 &&  2 Indexed[p3, {1}] == 3 && 2 Indexed[p3, {2}] == 3 &&  Indexed[p4, {1}] == 2 && Indexed[p4, {2}] == 0 &&  Indexed[p5, {1}] == 1 && Indexed[p5, {2}] == -(7/2) &&  Indexed[p6, {1}] == -1 && Indexed[p6, {2}] == -(3/2)

The command
NMinimize[{a[[1, 4, 1]], a[[1, 1, 2]],   a[[1, 4, 1]] >= 1}, {Indexed[q1, {1}], 
Indexed[q1, {2}], Indexed[q2, {1}], Indexed[q2, {2}], Indexed[q3, {1}],   Indexed[q3, {2}]}]

has quit the kernel in short time. In view of it we substitute
b=a[[1, 1, 2]] /. {Indexed[p1, {1}] -> -2, Indexed[p1, {2}] -> 0, 
Indexed[p2, {1}] -> -1, Indexed[p2, {2}] -> 5/2, Indexed[p3, {1}] -> 3/2, Indexed[p3, {2}] -> 3/2, 
Indexed[p4, {1}] -> 2 , Indexed[p4, {2}] -> 0, Indexed[p5, {1}] -> 1, 
Indexed[p5, {2}] -> -(7/2), Indexed[p6, {1}] -> -1, Indexed[p6, {2}] -> -(3/2), 
Indexed[q1, {1}] -> x1, Indexed[q1, {2}] -> y1, Indexed[q2, {1}] -> x2, 
Indexed[q2, {2}] -> y2, Indexed[q3, {1}] -> x3, Indexed[q3, {2}] -> y3};

Then (It takes a lot of time.)
NMinimize[{Area[Triangle[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]], b && 
Area[Triangle[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]] >= 1}, {x1, y1,  x2, y2, x3, y3},  
Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 100, "InitialPoints" -> {{-5, -5, 9, 9, 6, -5}}}]


{20.8002, {x1 -> 0.8, y1 -> -4.2, x2 -> -4.41595, y2 -> 3.62392,  x3 -> 2.39512, y3 -> 1.38293}}

Now we visualize the above by
tri = Region[Style[Triangle[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}] /.%[[2]],Blue]];
Show[tri,reg,Opacity->0.5]


Let us consider the case of the minimal area quadrilateral.
c = GeometricSolveValues[ GeometricScene[{q1, q2, q3, q4, p1 -> {-2, 0}, p2 -> {-1, 5/2}, 
 p3 -> {3/2, 3/2}, p4 -> {2, 0}, p5 -> {1, -7/2}, 
 p6 -> {-1, -3/2}}, {Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}], 
 GeometricAssertion[Polygon[{q1, q2, q3, q4}], "Convex"] &&
 p1 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3, q4}] && p2 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3, q4}] && p3 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3, q4}] && 
  p4 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3, q4}] && 
  p5 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3, q4}] && 
  p6 \[Element] Polygon[{q1, q2, q3, q4}]}], 
{q1, q2, q3, q4, Area[Polygon[{q1, q2, q3, q4}]]}] //FullSimplify;
d = c[[1, 1, 2]] /. {Indexed[p1, {1}] -> -2, Indexed[p1, {2}] -> 0, 
Indexed[p2, {1}] -> -1, Indexed[p2, {2}] -> 5/2, 
Indexed[p3, {1}] -> 3/2, Indexed[p3, {2}] -> 3/2, 
Indexed[p4, {1}] -> 2, Indexed[p4, {2}] -> 0, 
Indexed[p5, {1}] -> 1, Indexed[p5, {2}] -> -(7/2), 
Indexed[p6, {1}] -> -1, Indexed[p6, {2}] -> -(3/2), 
Indexed[q1, {1}] -> x1, Indexed[q1, {2}] -> y1, 
Indexed[q2, {1}] -> x2, Indexed[q2, {2}] -> y2, 
Indexed[q3, {1}] -> x3, Indexed[q3, {2}] -> y3, 
Indexed[q4, {1}] -> x4, Indexed[q4, {2}] -> y4}; 
NMinimize[{Area[Polygon[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}}]], d,
Area[Polygon[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}}]] >= 1}, 
{x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4}, 
Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "SearchPoints" -> 100 ,   "InitialPoints" -> {{-10, -10, -10, 10, 10, 10, 10, -10}}}]


{14.8227, {x1 -> -2.14285, y1 -> -0.357135, x2 -> -1.04024,  y2 -> 2.39939, x3 -> 2.34328, y3 -> 1.20144, x4 -> 1.,  y4 -> -3.50002}}


The question is: how to find $r[3,6]$ in the notations of the article with Mathematica? Without loss of generality we may consider
hexagons of the area one only.

I conjecture r[3, 6] = 3/2.

Saying exactly , I mean an numerical estimate for $r(3,6)$ obtained by NMinimize/NMaximize.

What was the value for your case depicted on the first image?

1.47258 if I am not mistaken.

Thank you for the interest to the question.  Could you kindly explain what the value you have in mind? Regard.

Isn't r ratio of areas? Area of triangle divided by area of hexagon.

I found the cited paper also in arXiv.

@A.Kato: Many thanks from me to you for the preprint. It is kind of you!

You're welcome. BTW, there is a typo in the title of your question.

@A.Kato: Thank you. Fixed.

By the way, isn't the case r[3,6] reduced to case r[3,4]=2 so that means that r[3,6]=r[3,4]=2?

Correction. I should have written I conjecture r[3, 6] is at least 3/2, i.e. r[3, 6] >= 3/2 in my first comment. And in my previous comment I should have written r[3,6]>=r[3,4], i.e. r[3,6]>=2.
